# Folders with .js files that I didnt create are in my pictures directory windows 10, virus?

Tags: malware, virus

About a month ago, two folders appeared in my /pictures directory named:

**Ready To Glare  (@ReadytoglareYT) _ Twitter_files** and **Lawrence's stream mom _ funhaus_files** .
Inside the folders are .js.download files, html files, .jpg files, and .png files, _api files(whatever that means), etc.

I didnt create them and never witnessed this type of behavior before. I tried a virus scan with Comodo Antivirus, Kasperski antivirus, and malwarebytes. They didnt find anything.

I cant find anything that would explain this on Google.

Anyone have any idea how this could have happened?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are files for saved webpages. I can almost completely guarantee that you've accidentally hit Ctrl+S in your browser and saved a page to your Pictures directory.

If you go up one folder, you'll almost certainly find a pair of HTML files that correspond to the folder names. The `_files` directories are where the resources (images, scripts, etc.) are saved for those saved HTML pages.

Comment: Wow, your right. I found the html files 1/^ up. I went to the site and tried to download that cat image by right clicking and ->*save as* and it defaults the save type to "webpage complete" instead of .jpg. Must be a twitter thing.

Comment: @eromod If you're looking at an image on Twitter where there are multiple pictures in an album, the left/right arrow elements completely cover the picture and prevent you from just doing right click -> save image. Instead, if you right click -> inspect element you can look a couple of elements up in the DOM inspector window and find the URL for the image you want to save.

Comment: yep, right click and inspecting the media got me the .jpg without the entire html. Here is the culprit pbs.twimg.com/media/D7d5aBpVsAAOL2y.jpg Thanks for the tip, saved me alot of headache.